# require 'sqlite3' fails after gem install sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

```
# gem which sqlite3
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3.rb
# irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'sqlite3'
LoadError: no such file to load -- sqlite3
        from (irb):1:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from :0
```

I am new to ruby but am experienced with Perl.  So I suspect its one of those library issues where sqlite3 got installed in a location that "gem" knows about but "irb" and "ruby" do not. Can anyone suggest a way I can fix this issue? thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have sqlite3 (the binaries, not the gem) installed? If you're using a linux distro you can use something like `sudo-apt get install sqlite3'.

Comment: I was able to get sqlite3 to load but only after I uninstalled the ruby I installed from my YUM repo and installed ruby 1.9 from source and then installed sqlite3 via the gem that got installed with ruby 1.9.

Comment: Great to hear that works! If I could recommend consider using rvm to manage your rubies. Also, in 2 days it should allow you to answer your question and mark it as an answer. That way the way the question will show up as closed and people in the future may benefit from your experience.

Comment: Thanks Sunny I will consider doing that

Comment: I don't know, but will the gem gets installed if the sqlite3 binaries are there, my immediate thought was, he was using ruby 1.8 and doesn't it require to `require 'rubygems'` before require any other gem? The problem got solved since he installed 1.9 which need not `require 'rubygems'`. Well using rvm is a better option than going for system ruby

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't basically because the binaries where missing. If the binaries for sqlite3 where missing for you, the `gem install sqlite3` would have failed right out, so the gem won't be installed. And won't be listed on `gem list` command.

What I read from the given output from terminal is that, you are using ruby 1.8.*, in these versions and below you need to `require 'rubygems'` first.

The problem was later solved, because, you upgraded your ruby to 1.9.*, in which you can right away require your gem without having to use `require 'rubygems'`.

It is always recommended to use rvm ruby. Details regarding installation and usage of rvm could be found [here](https://rvm.io/).